# How to get my Username in C# Code in Azure Web App while logged in with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App, where you sign in with Azure AD. Now I need to show the my own Name form AD on the Website, while logged in. Is there any way to get my Username in the C# Code?

There is a Tutorial, where you connect to Azure Graph to get your username.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user?tabs=command-line

This Tutorial doesn't work, because you have to change some Settings("additionalLoginParams") in ResourceExplorer. When you try that, you get an error, that its not possible, because you use auth v2.

There is also an other Tutorial, where you access the Graph, as well. But there you access the whole Azure AD Userlist and its not possible to define, which of the users is me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell%2Ccommand-line

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name from `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.user?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: That doesnt work. I log in to the Website with Azure AD. So in every HTTP Request to the Server, the Client sends a Token. But I think the Token is encrypted. So I can't just read the name like you said. Did you try it like this?

Comment: Yes. Are you sending the access token back to the server on each request?

Comment: Im not sure. I just use the normal Azure AD Authentification Settings for Web Service. So when you want to access the Website you get redirect to Microsoft Login and than to your website. I think for every HTTP Request to the Server the Client sends a Token. In this Token there has to be my Name form AD. Can you please send your example, how you get the name? Thanks :)

Comment: In my case, I am building an ASP.NET Web API protected by Azure AD (you have a web application). Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-dotnet-getting-started.